# Add a specific amount of time to a datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

i am using pandas.Timestamp.now(tz='America/New_York') to get the current time.

and using pandas.Timestamp.now(tz='America/New_York').date() to get current date

But I wanted to add 9hr 30min to the current date

```
pandas.Timestamp.now(tz='America/New_York').date() + pandas.Timedelta('570 minutes')
```

the following code is just giving date without the 9 hrs 30 minutes . Where should I improve ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably meant to call `normalize` before adding the two:

```
i = pandas.Timestamp.now(tz='America/New_York').normalize() 
j = pandas.Timedelta('570 minutes')
```

```
print(i + j) 
Timestamp('2018-06-05 09:30:00-0400', tz='America/New_York')
```

Comment: @ScottBoston ty Scott :)